# Dependency injection to module similar to using a class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this module in TypeScript (or ES2015, the code would be more or less identical) that I want to inject the route to:

```
var routeObject = express.Router();
var route: string = '/admin';

routeObject.get(route,
    (req, res, next) => {
        // Do something
        return next();
    },
    jade.View('admin')
);

export default routeObject;
```

In my `application.ts` file I import the module and use it like this:

```
server.Express.use(observationsRoute);
```

I want to be able to inject the path/route just as if I would have been using a class so that I can write something like this:

```
server.Express.use(observationsRoute('/admin'));
```

How could you achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export a functions that takes the route as an argument and return the `routeObject`:

```
export default (route: string) => {
    var routeObject = express.Router();

    routeObject.get(route + '/',
        (req, res, next) => {
            return next();
        },
        jade.View('admin')
    );

    return routeObject;
}
```